# Load dictionary items into spaCy NLP

Tags: python, spacy

I am struggling of finding an efficient way of loading all items from a python dictionary into spaCy NLP. My goal is to create a similarity function which can take an element from `dict1` and return the most similar element from `dict2`.

Since I am a newbie with both python and spacy, I only had the idea of looping over each item from `dict1`, performing `dict1_item = nlp(item)` then for each element of `dict2`, performing `dict2_item = nlp(item2)` and finally performing `similarity(dict1_item[dict2_item])`

I have not yet fully implemented this approach as the large amount of looping over gives me a hint that it would be incredibly slow.

Data wise I am comparing around 3 000 dict1 elements against 3 500 dict2 elements, that's why I am concerned about performance.

```
match_dict = {}
for elements in titles_dict: #dict1 full with job titles
    for title in title_dict[elements]:
        elem1 = nlp(title)
        for role in roles_listed: #dict2 full with role titles
            elem2 = nlp(role)
            similarity = elem1.similarity(elem2)
            if similarity >= .8:
                match_dict[elem1] = elem2
                break
```

My desire is to load all of dict1 and dict2 in nlp rather every element of it.

Something like:

```
doc1 = nlp(dict1.items())
doc2 = nlp(dict2.keys())
similarity = dic1.similarity(dic2)
```

and later I can store in a data frame the best matches.

Answer (score 0):

Use the spaCy pipeline to process all of your documents at once.

```
my_docs = list(docs)
nlp_docs = nlp.pipe(my_docs, batch_size = 100)
```

The `.similarity` function just calculates the cosine similarity using the NLP embedding vectors. We can extract the vectors like...

```
my_vecs = [doc.vector for doc in nlp_docs]
```

Grab the pairwise cosine similarity function from scikit-learn...

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import pairwise_distances

sim = 1 - pairwise_distances([vec1, vec2], metric='cosine')[0, 1]
```

Since you've already got all your nlp objects and vectors stored, hopefully looping through that calculation will be faster for you.